# Unable to run localhost in Spring Boot application (Tomcat server)

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-boot, pom.xml, spring-tool-suite

I've been learning Spring using the following tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTbx8p2oCgcAQGQyqN8XeA1x

I have created a Maven project and tried to run the Spring Boot application while referring to these videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7_a-kB46LU&index=9&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTbx8p2oCgcAQGQyqN8XeA1x

I tried to run my Spring application on Tomcat server but the localhost isn't working. (Port 8080)

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.javabrains.springbootquickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>course-api-new</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Java Brains Course API</name>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

</project>
```

CourseApiApp.java :

```
package io.javabrains.springbootstarter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CourseApiApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseApiApp.class, args);

    }

}
```

According to the video localhost should display Whitelist error on running the application, but it doesn't run at all.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: firstly. what do you meant by not running. Do you see any messages or exception. If so put stack trace. Next is in your pom, do you have spring boot maven plugin or not?

Comment: @pvpkiran Not running as in not executing anything on the browser saying "Localhost refused to connect". Yes there are errors shown in the STS but Spring starts without any problems. As for the plugin, I am unaware of it since I've just started learning this framework. Please check out the video link if it could be of use to you.

Comment: If you start your app, what messages appear in the console view?

Comment: @MartinLippert Sometimes, I get this Error: Could not find or load main class io.javabrains.springbootstarter.CourseApiApp .After somehow solving this error, Console doesn't show any errors but doesn't show any message related to "Tomcat started running on Port 8080" sorts. Also check out the video I'm referring to.

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest that you start your project from beginning. To create a valid `spring-boot` project you have a very good web based generator for `spring-boot` starter applications.

- https://start.spring.io/

For a web application with an embedded tomcat you should use `web` project.

[image]

Using `STS` you can create the same by choosing `new -> spring starter project`.

A wizard will appear and you can choose your project informations:

[image]

And then in the second step you dependencies:

[image]

After generating your project your `pom.xml` should look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Your application should start normally and tomcat listens on `localhost:8080`.

**EDIT**
The starter just have a new design:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Patrick , Thanks for your answer. I tried your method but localhost still doesn't run. I downloaded Eclipse instead of Spring tool suite, made a fresh project and still got the same problems. Could you suggest something else? Thanks.

Comment: @NavneetJoshi that is very strange. Can you please provide any more informations, exceptions and so on.

Comment: On running the program, STS alerts me that the project has errors (doesn't show what errors they are) but My CourseApiApp.java runs fine. But it fails to show any message related to "Tomcat started running...." and localhost:8080 shows "localhost refused to connect". I've tried adding port info to application.properties file but it leads to another error that previously existed, ie. "Could not find or load main class io.javabrains.springbootstarter.CourseApiApp". Please check out the video I was referring to if that helps.

Comment: How do I send you a screenshot of the Console?

Comment: how you choose web dependency now this option is not there in web

Comment: @DeV updated answer because starter have a new design. But web is still available

Answer (score 9):

**Solution: add web starter dependency to pom.xml for maven**

No need to create new app. Just change this starter dependency to starter-web dependency:

**Starter**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Starter Web**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to run spring-boot as sudo

```
sudo mvn spring-boot:run
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that STS by default uses Tomcat version 7 and if you happen to use version 8, then would need to specify the same in pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.47</tomcat.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. Try creating Spring Boot apprlication by choosing Spring Boot starter project in STS.
Right click on STS->New->Spring Starter Project->Give name and click on Next->Choose Web and tick mark on Web and search for Dev Tools and tick mark Dev Tools and click on Finish

Now click on the project and Run as Spring Boot Application.

Answer (score 0):

In application.properties put server.port=8080

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue. I too was following the JavaBrains SpringBoot example. This is what I did:
I created a fresh spring boot project using STS tool and included the same code as provided by you and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell springboot where do you have to scan your reference classes

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.testbean.controller", "com.testbean.model", "com.testbean.service"}) 
public class DemoApplication {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @ComponentScan("io.javabrains") and mention the package in which the Controller is present. eg.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("io.javabrains")
public class CourseApiApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseApiApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

In a spring boot application, by default spring searches for components in the same package which is having the @SpringBootApplication annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial to setup JavaJDK, Tomcat and Maven: `https://jeromejaglale.com/doc/spring4_tutorial/installation_macos`

Next step move to Terminal app: type `cd root_project` and run `sudo mvn spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve with a tip above the server.port

I added as said: server.port = 8090 and it worked.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lZAEaD5VZdpnyffROn9X37mZm4vaQJ9G/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please don't duplicate answers, next time just use vote up :-)