# What do I need to download to use SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm new at Spring and i'm going to use SpringBoot for a project but I can't understand how it works and what I need to download.

I have this java version:

```
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

And also have already installed Maven 3.6.3

Can anyone please tell me what I need to download for Spring and where I can find it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45033496/3493036

Comment: Try this https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to https://start.spring.io/ or use an IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse, NetBeans) to create a Spring Boot project.